# Extract value MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text, extract

I need to extract the first value of the following code:

3.43099,70.8539,91.701,FAIL

The file has the '.sol' extension, but it can be read in notepad or Matlab.

I just want to know how to to read in all *.sol files in a folder and how to write the extracted value in a text file.

Thanks a lot, i would be grateful.

NEW

```
ita='"';
for i=1:size(z,2)
word_to_replace=input('Replace? ','s');
tik=input('Replacement? ','s');
coluna=input('Column? ');
files = dir('*.txt');
for i = 1:numel(files)
    if ~files(i).isdir % make sure it is not a directory
        contents = fileread(files(i).name);
        fh = fopen(files(i).name,'w');
        val=num2str(z(i,coluna));
        word_replacement=strcat(tik,val,ita);
        contents = regexprep(contents,'word_to_replace','word_replacement');
        fprintf(fh,contents); % write "replaced" string to file
        fclose(fh) % close out file
    end
end
end
```

Many thanks

Comment: I need to extract the first value of the following code:

3.43099,70.8539,91.701,FAIL

The file has the '.sol' extension, but it can be read in notepad or Matlab.

I just want to know how to to read in all *.sol files in a folder and how to write the extracted value in a text file.

Thanks a lot, i would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File extension does not make a difference as to what MATLAB can "read", use the `fileread` command  to load in the file and parse its contents. You can then split on commas, since it looks like it is comma separated

```
files = dir('*.sol');
fh = fopen('outFile.txt','w');
for i = 1:numel(files)
    if ~files(i).isdir % make sure it is not a directory
        contents = fileread(files(i).name);
        parts = regexp(contents,',','Split');
        fprintf(fh,[parts{1},'\n']);
    end
end
fclose(fh)
```

This should do what you want. It will find all files in the current directory with the `.sol` extension, loop through all of them, grab the first value, and write it out to a text file.

**Find and replace**

Finding and replacing is relatively simple as well. You can do the same looping, read the file contents, run a replacement, and then rewrite that out to the same file.

```
files = dir('*.sol');
for i = 1:numel(files)
    if ~files(i).isdir % make sure it is not a directory
        contents = fileread(files(i).name);
        fh = fopen(files(i).name,'w'); % open handle to same file just read for overwriting
        contents = regexprep(contents,'toReplace','replacement'); % do string replacement
        fprintf(fh,contents); % write "replaced" string to file
        fclose(fh) % close out file
    end
end
```

Comment: Excuse me, but can you tell me if i can search for a string in a text file and replace with another that i want? Every ocurrence? Just like "find and replace all"? Thanks in advance

Comment: No problem. One thing I suggest is not just taking the code for granted and copying and pasting. Read and understand each line and what/how it works. This will build your skills, and you will end up better off later. Programming is the art of using small building blocks to build something much more complex

Comment: Ok, but can you answer my previous question? Can i edit a text file in matlab? Replace a text for another? Every Occurrence? Thanks, grateful

Comment: answer updated to reflect string replacement as well

Comment: I cant do it, it says 1 reputation required and i'm new. It is my first post. Sorry man :s

Comment: Sorry to bother you again sir, but in the code i could replace the ~files(i).isdir for ~isdir('files(i)')? What does the "." in the code? Is like a abreviation of code? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @user3641311 If you have a new question, you should ask it as a new question, instead of in the comments to an answer to a different question.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 I have changed the code but it doesn' replace anything in the text files. Could you help me? The text files have the same words, not the news. Thanks in advance

Comment: I do not know how you changed anything therefor how can I help you.